# A question in the context of the Frattini subgroup $\Phi(G)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

I am reading the following short proposition. Everything is clear except the inference in red. Note that $\Phi(G)$ is the *Frattini subgroup* of $G$ and $H$ char $G$ means that $H$ is a *characteristic subgroup* of $G$. 
[image]

..    [image]

**Question**: Why does $P \Phi(G)/\Phi(G)$ char $N/\Phi(G)$ imply $P \Phi(G)$ char $N$ below?

Thank you for your insights!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that $H\unlhd G$ means that $H$ is just normal in $G$ in this context. You mean $H\operatorname{char}G$.

Comment: It may have something to do with the fact that the Frattini subgroup of $G$ is characteristic in $G$????

Comment: You could argue slightly differently: $P\Phi(G)/\Phi(G)\  {\rm char}\ N/\Phi(G) \Rightarrow P\Phi(G)/\Phi(G) \unlhd G/\Phi(G) \Rightarrow P\Phi(G) \unlhd G$.

Comment: The fourth sentence of the proof is wrong, as you can see by considering the case where $G$ is a $p$-group and $N=\Phi(G)$. Nevertheless it is still true that $P\Phi(G)\lhd G$, so the rest goes through.

Comment: @KeithKearnes actually which sentence are you referring to?

Comment: The fourth sentence of the proof.

Comment: @hellotinfish: Yes, you are right! Sorry for the typo.

Comment: @Derek Holt: Your argument seams plausible to me! Thank you very much: so it was "obvious" after all - I only lacked the necessary insight. If you want to make a short answer out of your comment I am more than happy to give you credit.